# trying to integrate justboil.me in tinymce and i get "/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english resource not found" error

Tags: java, image-uploading, rich-text-editor, tinymce-4, justboil.me

I am trying to integrate justboil.me with tinymce. The dialog opens fine but after i select the image the upload hangs and it gives me the error saying the "**unable top access jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english**". Any help with this is much appreciated.